# this undefined inside of javascript prototype method

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am using a build tool with ES6 support, and I have the following code:

```
function Message(subject, body) {
    this.subject = subject;
    this.body = body;
    this.unread = true;
}

Message.prototype.markAsRead = function() {
    this.unread = false;
}

export {Message};
```

Later in another file when I do this:

```
import {Message} from './application/Message.js';
var message = new Message("hey", "there");
message.markAsRead();
```

I get the following error inside of the `markAsRead()` method:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'unread' of undefined
```

A console log of `this` inside that method return `undefined`.

Is it the way I'm importing/exporting Message? Is it something deprecated in ES6? I don't have this problem when I write ES5 JS, but I figure it's something simple that I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The quoted code is fine, perhaps you over-simplified for the question? For instance, is your real code calling `markAsRead` as a callback? E.g., `doSomethingAsync(message.markAsRead)`, because *that* would have the symptom you've described (because you lose the meaning of `this`).

Comment: As TJ says, *this* is set by the call, so if you aren't actually calling the method as `message.markAsRead()` then you may not be setting *this* correctly. Though in non–strict mode it should default to the global object and the error would be different.

Comment: Yes, I did simplify the question, and yes, it is being used as a callback (it's actually a Vue.js call inside of `v-on:click="..."`. Looks like moving that into a dedicated wrapper method in the Vue instance resolved the problem.

Comment: @AgmLauncher please delete your question if you solved it and the description isn't even accurate.